# pandas concatenate list of data frames with different columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

```
data=pd.concat(a,ignore_index=True,axis=0)
```

a is a list of dataframes with different shape and columns but most of them are the same, I want to concatenate it into one dataframe but received an error.

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'

Comment: please provide a [minimal,complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map(dict,a)) @Vazgen

Comment: I tried your code and receive an error 'data argument can't be an iterator'

Comment: Could you add an example of your data? I've tried run pd.concat with a list of data frames with different shape and columns. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are ok with having `None` in the non-shared columns. Something like this will work. It creates an empty column in the corresponding DataFrames where needed using [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
# generate a sample scenario
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'shared1': range(7),
    'col1': range(7)
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'shared1': range(7),
    'col2': range(7)
})

# make columns the same by adding empty columns
for c in df2.columns:
    if c not in df1.columns:
        df1[c] = None
for c in df1.columns:
    if c not in df2.columns:
        df2[c] = None
df1.append(df2)
```